# Unable to load Stripe 3ds iframe on Cordova

Tags: cordova, iframe, stripe-payments, content-security-policy

I'm having hard time trying to implement 3ds for stripe.
Since I updated to cordova 10, android@9.1 and ios@6.2 I can't load anymore iframe for 3ds. The intent is set correctly and I receive 3ds text message on my Phone but I can't see the iFrameContent. I tried to change Content-Security-Policy in index.html and allow-navigation in config.xml.

These are my `config.xml` properties:

```html
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="about:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

Here how I set the CSP:

```html
<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="
             connect-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
             script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
             frame-src https://*.stripe.com;"
>
```

And this is the error I get:

[image: error]

According to stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#additional-security-considerations) you need to append these rules to your CSP

[image: stripe]

But still I can't load the iframe containing the 3ds.

[image]

Any clue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this for everyone who's struggling on the same issue. I managed to solve the issue by moving stripe logic and card management outside Cordova default browser wrapper (which is **WKWebView**). I've reached stripe support and they also think this is related to **WKWebView** security.

Just install *cordova-plugin-inappbrowser* and comunicate with your app using `InAppBrowser.addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

try using ionic webkit `"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"`, adding

```
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="true" />
    <preference name="Scheme" value="https" />
    <preference name="MixedContentMode" value="2" />
```

to your config.xml (this are ionic-webview specific), last add `frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.stripe.com;` to your csp configuration.

It worked for me